# SAS - Create a month and year date from one integer

Tags: date, sas

I have a data set in which month and year are in one variable and come in the form 200801 which equates to 2008, January. How can I create a SAS date from this integer?

I would like something in the form of Jan 2008 - anything so that SAS recognizes it as a date, as I then need to subtract this value from service date to find out how much time has elapsed since enrollment into the dataset until date of service.

Please also keep in mind that this is a variable, and I have thousands of observations. So I also need the data step/ function to do this for the entire variable.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put it to a character variable, then input back to numeric.  You can do that pretty easily.

```
date_var = input(put(date_var_orig,6.)||'01',yymmdd8.);
```

You can also do it this way:

```
date_var = mdy(mod(date_var_orig,100),1,floor(date_var_orig/100));
```

Both assume you want the day to equal 1; make a choice there if you want something else (like end of month or middle of month).